# Language of Laravel Resource Controller

Tags: php, rest, laravel, routes

I'm from the Netherlands and I'm making a website using Laravel 5.2 in Dutch. I want to be able to use the `Route::resource('test', 'testController')` with Dutch names as the methods of the controller. So basically I want to change the following action names:

1. /index becomes /thuis
2. /create becomes /maken
3. /store becomes /opslaan
4. ...

and so on..

Is this possible and how would I do it? I don't want to create a single route for every possible action.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you will be a little bit patient... This is so funny, cause right now I'm building a package for that! I'm Dutch too. With that package you can use it like: `TranslatableRoute::resource('recipe', 'recepten', 'RecipeController');` Only thing is I use the same route stucture as normal resource routes so /index is still just / and store is also just /. Only create and edit becomes "nieuw" and "wijzig"

Comment: @TimvanUum That's awesome! Please hit me up when you finished it :-) what you're making is pretty much enough for what I need, it's just for the customers of the site to understand the URL. The methods can be in English though, that doesn't matter.

Comment: if you go to webchat.freenode.net and add "translatableroute" as channel we could talk more easily.

Comment: almost done, having some trouble autoloading the package. @Helix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My package is ready for use. Just follow the instructions. Don't forget to set your locale to nl or in the future to another language.

https://github.com/doitonlinemedia/TranslatableRoutes

You can call the resource routes like:

`TranslatableRoute::resource('recipe', 'recepten', 'RecipeController');`

Where the second argument is the translated name and the first defines the name of your routes.

See also: https://codeneverlied.com/translatable-resource-routes-in-laravel/

Answer (score 0):

I think methods and routes naming have to be in english to keep your code readable by other developers in the world.

Contribution and debugging are easier with a generic language.

Comment: so you want people that don't speak english to have urls with the word 'create' and 'edit' in them?

Comment: Yes, using english is more a convention. I'm French and at my begins, I used french for methods and routes naming. The problem with this approach is the code is not conventional, and so, non readable by all other developers.
If you write a package that you want share or publish, other developers which doesn't speak your specific language can't understand your code correctly. It's very limited for contributing, declaring issues, ...
Learn and write code in english is the easier solution. More, Composer and required development tools for laravel are written in english. Translate only the content

Comment: @chalasr it's totally fine to use url's in a specific language. It's even better for SEO. But indeed, method names and coding should be in English.

Comment: english for code maybe, but urls, which are user facing, should have meaning.